# How to define the grid (for using grid search) from scratch in Python?

Tags: python, grid-search

I write a function that accepts a dictionary of parameter names (could be of any size>0) and numeric values, and returns a list of dictionaries with all the possible combinations.

For example:

```
myFunc({'ParA':[1,2,3], 'ParB': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]})
```

Will return

```
[{'ParA':1, 'ParB':0.1},{'ParA':1, 'ParB':0.2}...{'ParA':2, 'ParB':0.1}....{'ParA':3, 'ParB':0.4}]
```

Normally I'd use nested loops, but I do not know the number of parameters in advance.

Another challenge is that the number of possible values in each parameter changes, so the lengths are not sorted in the dictionary.

Is there a smart way of doing that?

**Note: it has to be from scratch, so no grid-search functions from SciPy**

Comment: use `itertools.product`

Comment: @Julien Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution based on Julien's answer ([`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)):

```
def makeGrid(pars_dict):  
    keys=pars_dict.keys()
    combinations=itertools.product(*pars_dict.values())
    ds=[dict(zip(keys,cc)) for cc in combinations]
    return ds
```

Comment: Note that there is no need to cast to a list, as you only iterate it once.  Doing so loses you the advantages of an iterator for no gain.  Also, return is a statement, not a function, so you should write `return ds` (although what you have written is not invalid).  Although personally I would just return the listcomp without assigning a variable just to return it (which winds linters up).

Comment: @2e0byo Thanks! I changed my solution.